# Android ListView: Can't add sms/inbox items to ListView using cursor

Tags: android, listview, sms, cursor, listadapter

I am trying to call "body" and "address"  from content://sms/inbox and add them to a ListView.

"address" going to the Item1 in the ListView, "body" going to SubItem in same ListView.

To do this, I am implementing a Cursor to add these items to the ListView.

When running the code how I have it now, I get no errors or crashes, but there is nothing added to my ListView at all.  I have all of the permissions needed in the manifest.

Not sure where I went wrong :( But thanks in advance!

My XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/header__root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/burntorange"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="147dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.13"
        android:background="@color/burntorange"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Messages"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bNewMessage"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:background="@color/gray"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="handleClick"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="New Thread"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

My Menu.java:

```
public class Menu extends ListActivity {

ListView itemList;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle biscuits) {
    super.onCreate(biscuits);

    setContentView(R.layout.header);

    itemList = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);


    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    startManagingCursor(c);

    String[] number = new String [c.getCount()];
    String[] body = new String [c.getCount()];

    if(c.moveToFirst()){
        for (int i=0; i<c.getCount();i++) {
            body[i]=c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString();
            number[i] =c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString();
            c.moveToNext();

    List<Map<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    Map<String, String> datum = new HashMap<String, String>(2);

    datum.put("contactNumber", number[i]);
    datum.put("messagePreview", body[i]);

    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, 
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            new String[] {"contactNumber", "messagePreview"},
            new int [] {android.R.id.text1,
                        android.R.id.text2});

    itemList.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
    }       
}

public void handleClick(View v) {

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(this, TextActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);              
}

protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String cheese = (String) l.getItemAtPosition(position);
    Toast.makeText(this, cheese + " Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    try {
        Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.example.mytexts." + cheese);
        Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, ourClass);
        startActivity(ourIntent);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: did you check the cursor count? and arent you setting the adapter too many times?

Comment: Sorry, new to this cursor business.  How do I check the cursor count, and I believe I have only one instance where I set the adapter.. Just itemList.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: log the c.getCount(). you are doing setAdapter inside for loop. You need to do it outside after you have filled the map

Comment: This scenario is why there is a CursorAdapter. Have you tried using CursorAdapter. Might make your life easier.